# difference between numpy.convolve and scipy signal.convolve

Tags: python

now I have a numpy   2D array and want to make a convolution with a 2D kernel. I have tried using numpy.convolve  and the out put was :

ValueError: object too deep for desired array

when trying signal.convolve it works well .

so is there any way to fix np.convolve??

and is the result of signal.convolve will be the same as np.convolve
?

here is my simple code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b=np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
A=np.convolve(a,b,'same')

out:ValueError: object too deep for desired array 

B=signal.convolve(a,b,'same')
Out[53]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  5],
   [ 5, 12, 16]])
```

Comment: Numpy.convolve accepts 1D arrays, this is explicitly pointed out in [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)

Comment: So if I want to do convolution for 2D arrays using unmpy it is impossible?

Comment: You can probably implement it by your own using fast fourier transform or use signal.convolve.

Answer (score 1):

**numpy.convolve** is designed to work with one-dimensional arrays and is not meant to be used directly for two-dimensional arrays. However, you can use **numpy.convolve** to perform a convolution on each row and column of the 2D array separately, which effectively results in a 2D convolution.

Here's an example of how to perform a 2D convolution using **numpy.convolve**:

```
 import numpy as np
 # Define the 2D array and kernel
 arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
 kernel = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]])

 # Perform convolution on each row
 conv_row = np.apply_along_axis(np.convolve, axis=1, arr=arr, v=kernel[:,0], mode='same')
 for i in range(1, kernel.shape[1]):
     conv_row += np.apply_along_axis(np.convolve, axis=1, arr=arr, v=kernel[:,i], mode='same')

 # Perform convolution on each column
 conv_col = np.apply_along_axis(np.convolve, axis=0, arr=conv_row, v=kernel[0,:], mode='same')
 for i in range(1, kernel.shape[0]):
     conv_col += np.apply_along_axis(np.convolve, axis=0, arr=conv_row, v=kernel[i,:], mode='same')

 # Output the result 
 print(conv_col)
```

Note that this approach may not be as efficient as using **scipy.signal.convolve2d**, especially for larger arrays and kernels, but it provides an alternative method using only **numpy**.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).